# Calculated Field - Syntax Error

Tags: ms-word, syntax-error, mailmerge, word-2010

I am running a mail merge off a data set where I have fields "pledge" and "distance"

`{ pledge }` Yields a correct value when the merge is previewed.

Yet...

`{ ={ pledge}*{distance} }` Results in a syntax error.

How can I get this field to calculate correctly?

Answer (score 1):

`{ =pledge * distance}` fixed it